# Selecting most realistic C and g params after gridsearch

Tags: machine-learning, svm, cross-validation, libsvm

I just ran an extended SVC gridsearch in libsvm on about 9000 multi-dimensional vectors representing a time series. Here are the highest scoring results:

```
[local] 3 -7 72.4729 (best c=0.5, g=0.5, rate=76.9618)
..
[local] -1 -5 71.79 (best c=8.0, g=0.5, rate=77.4432)
..
[local] 15 -11 73.0326 (best c=2048.0, g=0.03125, rate=77.5887)
..
[local] -5 -3 66.0249 (best c=32768.0, g=0.03125, rate=77.723)
..
[local] 7 -3 77.9245 (best c=128.0, g=0.125, rate=77.9245)
```

Here's the contour of the cross validation accuracy:

[image]

Given the above I'm very tempted to settle on either a C value of 0.5 or 8.0 - anything above 100 seems heavily over fitted to me. Especially given the rather minuscule success rate differences.

Any thoughts, insights, or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would go for $C=0.5$ since the difference in accuracy is most likely neglectable and the model is much stronger regularized, e.g. [simpler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor).

Comment: Thanks Marc - you are basically confirming my own thoughts - much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of making an SVM implement a smooth model, the first is to make the regularisation parameter large, the other is to make the kernel function smooth (i.e. less sensitive to the values of its parameters).  There isn't a-priori much of a reason to prefer one method of making the model simple over the other, so choosing a combination to minimise the cross-validation error is a reasonable thing to do.  In practice any combination of values lying along the bottom of the valley in the contour plot will be pretty much as good as any other.

If you don't have too many hyper-parameters to tune and are not minimising the cross-validation too aggressively (a coarse grid search is fine), then you won't have a real problem with [over-fitting the model selection criterion](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf), so anything along the bottom of the valley will do.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your insights, Dikran. I'm actually quite paranoid about overfitting as the time series is of financial nature (futures price series - as you can see from the plot title) and quite many more experienced folks have tried and failed in that particular department. Thus I have actually spent several weeks carefully preparing the input data, attempting to acquire a deeper understanding of what vector data would be of use in what format and in what context. This is just raw price data and as it was my first attempt it looks encouraging.

Comment: BTW, I would have voted you up but I don't even have enough reputation to do that. Tough rules here!

Comment: no problem, I'm glad you found the info useful.  Being paranoid about over-fitting is not too bad a thing when using complex models!

Comment: +1. (I suspect you have quoted the Cawley paper in the past actually...)

Comment: indeed, I wrote it because it is a point that crops up rather a lot in fitting kernel models (and indeed any model that has hyper-parameters).